# SwiftUI Divider not sizing itself to fit parent view?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, divider

I have a fairly basic SwiftUI view heirarcy that I'm attempting to insert a divider into, however the divider is sizing itself to some obscure value and pushing the parent view out to meet it. Every other view in the heirarchy is behaving correctly and the parent view is wrapping the largest child, as expected.

I've searched and searched and just can't find any insight into this behaviour - so I'm asking you good folks for some thoughs.

View code:

```swift
Form {
    HStack(alignment: .top) {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Picker("Paper Size:", selection: $viewModel.layoutParameters.paperSize) {
                ForEach(PrintSize.allCases, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0.description)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)
                    
            Picker(selection: $viewModel.layoutParameters.margin) {
                ForEach(Margin.allCases, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0.description)
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Margins:")
                    .padding(.leading, 15) // This is janky, find a better way to do it.
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)
        }
                
        Divider()
                
        Picker("Default Print Size:", selection: $viewModel.layoutParameters.printSize) {
            ForEach(PrintSize.allCases, id: \.self) {
                Text($0.description)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(.menu)
    }
}
.padding(8)
```

Exhibited behaviour with divider:
[image: With divider]

Without divider:
[image]

Bonus points if you can give me a way to nudge the Margins label over without explicitly applying padding.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Mac windows are resizable and the system stores the last settings. Do you want it to be fixed size?

Comment: And you can use `.fixedSize()` the get rid of that manual padding (but you should specify the correct formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the issues that you describe can be solved by using overlays.

1. A `Divider` is greedy and expands to use all the space available, just like a `Spacer`. To constrain it to the height of the `HStack`, just put it in an overlay over the `HStack`. By default, the overlay will be aligned to the center of the `HStack`. This is perfect, because the two `Picker` will have equal widths, so the `Divider` will automatically be positioned in the middle between them. However, two extra steps are needed to get it looking right:

- The orientation of a `Divider` is normally determined by the stack that contains it, or horizontal by detault. Since you want it to be vertical, it needs to be nested inside a dummy `HStack`.
- You will probably want to increase the `spacing` that is used by the `HStack`, since there is now only one space between the two `Picker`.

2. If you want the label for "Margins" to have the same width as the label for "Paper Size" then you can establish the footprint needed by using a hidden version of the longer label. Then show the shorter label in an overlay.

Here is an updated version of your example with the two changes applied:

```swift
Form {
    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 20) { // <- spacing added
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Picker("Paper Size:", selection: $viewModel.layoutParameters.paperSize) {
                ForEach(PrintSize.allCases, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0.description)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)

            Picker(selection: $viewModel.layoutParameters.margin) {
                ForEach(Margin.allCases, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0.description)
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Paper Size:")
                    .hidden()
                    .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
                        Text("Margins:")
                    }
//                    .padding(.leading, 15) // This is janky, find a better way to do it.
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)
        }

//        Divider()

        Picker("Default Print Size:", selection: $viewModel.layoutParameters.printSize) {
            ForEach(PrintSize.allCases, id: \.self) {
                Text($0.description)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(.menu)
    }
    .overlay {
        HStack {
            Divider()
        }
    }
}
.padding(8)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Instead of that hardcoded spacing, you can add a `hidden` `fixedSized` `Divider` as a placeholder

Comment: You can also factor out `.pickerStyle(.menu)` and apply it once on the main view.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini A hidden divider with fixed size indeed works, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I didn't know overlays were a thing so that's a helpful revalation - thanks. Verified as solving the issue though I'm still unsure whether I prefer the dummy lable (which has a bit of a code smell to me) or the grid solution which seems more 'proper', though overengineered. Time will tell which stays but both verified as working.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are using Xcode Previews. Previews behave a little differently from running the app normally.

If you run the app normally, the window sizes will be the same for both cases (whatever the macOS default window size is, or whatever is stored in your preferences), and you can resize both to the smallest size possible. **The sizes you see is just a Xcode Preview quirk.**

Notice that without a `Divider`, you can still resize the window to as big as you want, and the `HStack` sits in the middle, without changing its height, and there are lots of blank space below and above. On the other hand, the `Picker`s will expand horizontally, the `HStack`'s width can change.

Preview tries to display your view without any of those surrounding blank space. This is why you get a window that nicely fits the `HStack` when there is no `Divider`. Notice that the preview window's width is the default macOS window width. This is because the pickers are greedy and tries to take up as much horizontal space as possible - the preview has to stop it *somewhere*.

`Divider`s are also greedy, and tries to expand vertically as much as possible. When there is a `Divider`, the `Text` all gets aligned at the top (because `HStack(alignment: .top)`) when the height of the `HStack` is greater than the height of the pickers combined. Also, there is none of the "surrounding blank space" above and below anymore, because there is always the `Divider` to fill that space. The preview chooses the macOS default height for windows (again, it has to stop the expansion *somewhere*), which is a larger number than the height of the pickers combined.

Previews could have been designed to resize the window to its minimum size, but it wasn't designed like that. I'd imagine lots of views would look rather cramped this way.

I'm not sure there is a way for previews to show the minimum sized-window. You can force the preview to use a particular sized window though:

```
#Preview(traits: .fixedLayout(width: 500, height: 100)) {
    ContentView()
}
```

You can also try putting `.fixedSize` on the `HStack`, but this resizes to its "ideal size", not its minimum size. The "ideal size" is still quite a lot larger than the minimum size.

```
// you can also set the ideal size
// .frame(idealHeight: 100)
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

As for aligning the labels, I would use a `Grid`:

```
Grid(alignment: .trailing, horizontalSpacing: 8, verticalSpacing: 8) {
    GridRow {
        Text("Paper Size:")
        Picker("", selection: .constant(1)) {
            // Dummy data for the picker...
            Text("Foo").tag(1)
        }
    }
        
    GridRow {
        Text("Margins:")
        Picker("", selection: .constant(1)) {
            Text("Bar").tag(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Side note: you can put `.pickerStyle(.menu)` on the `HStack`, instead of each picker. It applies that style to all the children.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination regarding the previews, makes sense. Additonally the tip about attributes propagating to children (I feel like I knew this but didn't apply it for some reason). The grid approach feels quite excessive but then has less of a smell to it than a dummy label, so the jury's out on what I keep but I've verified both as working.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is concerning `Form`.
The behavior you're experiencing with the `Divider` in your SwiftUI view hierarchy could be due to the way SwiftUI calculates the layout of views. The `Divider` view, by default, expands to fill the available width. This can cause unexpected layout issues if it's placed within a container view that has a flexible width, such as an `HStack`.
You can try this:

```swift
Form {
    // Your existing code...
    
    HStack(alignment: .top) {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            // Your existing code...
        }
        
        Divider()
            .frame(height: 1) // Set the height of the Divider to 1 point
            .padding(.vertical, 8) // Add vertical padding to match the other views
            .background(Color.gray) // Optionally, add a background color to the Divider
            .padding(.horizontal, 8) // Add horizontal padding to match the other views
    }
    
    // Your existing code...
}
```

By setting the height of the `Divider` to 1 point using the frame modifier, you can control its size independently from the other views in the `HStack`. Additionally, you can add padding and a background color to match the styling of the other views in your view hierarchy.

Give this modification a try and see if it resolves the layout issue with the `Divider` in your SwiftUI view hierarchy.